# Else Loop only runs once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I'm running an else loop to iterate through an XML file in ruby, assigning values to a hash. There are 3 items in the XML file, but for some reason it only iterates through the first one, any idea why?

```
require "nokogiri"

f= File.open("untitled.xml")

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)

    f.close 

    doc.xpath('//item').each do |node|

       children = node.children

      item = {
      "name" => node['name'], 
      "buyItNowPrice"=> children.css('buytItNowPrice').inner_text, 
      "description" => children.css('description').inner_text, 
      "startingBidPrice" => children.css('startingBidPrice').inner_text,
      "closing_time" => children.css('closing_time').inner_text,
      "closing_date" => children.css('closing_date').inner_text
      }

    puts item
    end
```

XML:

```
<item name = "Test Thing">
  <description>Something Coolest.</description>
  <buytItNowPrice>154.99</buytItNowPrice>
  <startingBidPrice>9999.99</startingBidPrice>
  <closing_date>2014-12-25</closing_date>
  <closing_time>12:32:PM</closing_time>
</item>

<item name = "Lazer">
  <description>Something Cool.</description>
  <buytItNowPrice>149.99</buytItNowPrice>
  <startingBidPrice>9.99</startingBidPrice>
  <closing_date>2014-12-25</closing_date>
  <closing_time>12:32:PM</closing_time>
</item>

<item name = "Pokemon">
  <description>Something even cooler.</description>
  <buytItNowPrice>33.99</buytItNowPrice>
  <startingBidPrice>9.99</startingBidPrice>
  <closing_date>2014-12-25</closing_date>
  <closing_time>12:32:PM</closing_time>
</item>
```

Output is only the the first item printed.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but maybe because your XML isn't valid? Try wrapping your `<item>`s in a `<items>` root node and iterate through that.

Comment: I created an answer from that comment, you should be able to mark it as accepted in a few minutes. Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 1):

The given sample XML isn't valid.

A valid XML document requires a single root node, right now you have 3.

You could fix this by wrapping all the `<item>` nodes in a `<items>` root node, and iterate through its children then.